# How can I detect an object (with the camera) within an image, and make a new image of this object?

Tags: iphone, image, camera, edge-detection

Within my project I'm using the camera function of the iPhone. I'd like to take a picture of a card (Rectangle shape). After I take this picture I'd like to scale and fit this card to a new image.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for making these functions? (are there any libraries or so?)

Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). It's easy to [port](http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en) it on iPhone. But it isn't so easy to use it. Grab a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) about OpenCV for weekend reading and on monday you'll easy solve your task.